# How to check the total number of papers published by a country at a certain conference?

Tags: conference

I presented a paper at a top-tier conference, and I would like to know how many papers from our country have been presented at this conference? Also, I would like to know how many papers from our school have been presented at this conference? Where does my paper rank? How should I inquire? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean in the past as well as for the current conference?

Comment: I mean: For example, I would like to know how many papers our school has published at the ISCA conference up to this point, and what is the ranking of the paper I presented at this conference among the papers published by our school. And what is the ranking of our country in terms of the number of papers published at the conference?  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is not typically such a "ranking" of conference papers. There could sometimes be an awards process to assign a "best paper" but this does not imply that all papers have been ranked (and especially not in a way they could be compared across years). Any rough ranking by, say, reviewer scores would not really be an appropriate way to rank papers against each other, since the reviewers will have different standards. This would be a near-impossible task, in any case. I would abandon the thought entirely.

Some conferences may collect and report participation statistics, but I question the meaning of papers being published by *countries*. A paper can have any number of authors from any number of places, and assigning a given paper to a specific country may not be possible. In any event, this will almost certainly have to be your own endeavor: you would need to programmatically collect details on each paper in the conference yourself and use some criteria to sort them. I would not expect that there is a place these numbers are easily available to you without extensive effort.

Comment: Thank you! But I just want to inquire about my position as the nth person from our school to present a paper at this top-tier conference. This information is for my job application resume.

Comment: @Gerrie To do that, it seems you'd need a list of all previous people presenting at this conference and their schools. I do not expect this to be available in some already-compiled form. Is it worth the trouble?

Comment: In simpler terms, I would like to know the position of my paper among the papers published by our school at this conference. This seems like a straightforward count. For example, if my paper is the fifth one, it means that our school has previously published four papers at this conference.

Comment: I understand what you're looking for (I would not have called this a rank, but it's now clear what you mean). Many things are conceptually straightforward but difficult to perform in practice without the necessary data.